# Display a link if an item has a PDF in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get an item to display a link to PDF if that item has a PDF associated with it. I am not sure how the if statement would be formatted. I am using Laravel for this.

Here is the code that I have in the controller for the item:

```
 //PDF Upload
    if($request->hasFile('spec_sheet')) {
        //Get file name and extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('spec_sheet')->getClientOriginalName();
        //Get just file name
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get Ext
        $extension = $request->file('spec_sheet')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //Store file name
        $fileNameOfPdfToStore = $filename. '.' .$extension;
        //Upload
        $path = $request->file('spec_sheet')->storeAs('public/mcelroy-specs', $fileNameOfPdfToStore);
    }

    $rental = new Rental;

    $rental->title = $request->title;
    $rental->name = $request->name;
    $rental->description = $request->description;
    $rental->product_image = $fileNameToStore; 
    $rental->spec_sheet = $fileNameOfPdfToStore;          

    $rental->save();
```

In the view I have this:

```
@foreach($rentals as $rental)
        <article class="cards-item">
            <figure class="card product">
                <div class="card-images">
                    <img src="/storage/rentals/{{$rental->product_image}}" alt="" >
                </div>
                <figcaption class="card-content">
                <h1 class="card-title">{{ $rental->title }}</h1>
                <h2 class="card-title product_title">{{ $rental->name }}</h2>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align:left;">{{ $rental->description }}
                    @if(!empty($spec_sheet))
                    <a href="{{$rental->spec_sheet}} " target="_blank">Download Spec Sheet</a>
                    @endif

                </p>
                <form action="{{ route('cart.store') }} " method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $rental->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ $rental->title }}">
                    {{-- <input type="hidden" name="pickupDate" value="{{ $rental->pickupDate }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="returnDate" value="returnDate"> --}}
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div class="back">
                            <button class="primary button" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </article>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for the right way to do something in Laravel, but there is no right way.

Given

```
@if(!empty($spec_sheet))
   <a href="{{$rental->spec_sheet}} " target="_blank">Download Spec Sheet</a>
@endif
```

I would make two changes, 1) shouldn't `$spec_sheet` be `$rental->spec_sheet`? and 2) swap out the `@if(!empty(...))` with `@unless(empty())` as I feel that including a `!` will make it harder to understand when you come back to this in a few weeks.

So I am suggesting you use this which should be just fine, since there's no right way to do this in Laravel.

```
@unless(empty($rental->spec_sheet))
   <a href="{{$rental->spec_sheet}} " target="_blank">Download Spec Sheet</a>
@endunless
```

Comment: that does do the trick. I have never seen the unless statement before so thank you. One thing is happening though, when you click the link it opens into another page that has the laravel message of “page not found” it should just open up the pdf file.

Comment: Never mind, it was a path naming error for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above will not work if there is no PDF attached, as the variable $fileNameOfPdfToStore will not exist and a hard error will be thrown. But assuming you fix that issue and store an empty string for the file name or perhaps NULL instead of the file path, then you could create a new attribute in the Rental model that looks like this:

```
public function getHasSpecSheetAttribute() {
    return $this->spec_sheet==null? false:true;
}
```

Then in your view you would do this:

```
@if($rental->hasSpecSheet)
    <a href="{{$rental->spec_sheet}} " target="_blank">Download Spec Sheet</a>
@endif
```

In order to fix the PDF upload code, just put an else statement and put this inside of it:

```
$fileNameOfPdfToStore = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(strlen({$rental->spec_sheet) > 0))
      <a href="{{$rental->spec_sheet}} " target="_blank">Download Spec Sheet</a>
@endif
```

use string length to determine if there was file name uploaded or not